# Querying db-sync for ADA Balance

Tags: cardano-db-sync

I want to write the ADA balance of my wallet to a console window using sql queries against the db-sync database.

How can I use sql statements to obtain the ADA balance of a given address by querying db-sync via postgresql? I tried querying the sum of the [value] of the utxo's of my wallet but seem to get inaccurate results acording to what my Eternl wallet says my balance is. Somehow I am misunderstanding what I should be summing etc.

There is no straightforward query for "wallet balance" in the interesting queries in the db-sync git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tx_out` table contains both **spent** and **unspent** tx outputs. In order to calculate your balance, you need to sum only the **unspent** outputs.

We can check which outputs are unspent by joining on the `tx_in` table. If there is no associated entry for a particular `tx_out` row in the `tx_in` table, this output has not been spent.

Here are the associated queries for calculating both address and stake address balances:

```sql
-- address balance
select sum(tx_out.value)
from tx_out
left join tx_in on tx_in.tx_out_id = tx_out.tx_id and tx_in.tx_out_index = tx_out.index
where address = '<your-address-here>'
  and tx_in.id is null

-- stake address balance
select sum(tx_out.value)
from stake_address
inner join tx_out on tx_out.stake_address_id = stake_address.id
left join tx_in on tx_in.tx_out_id = tx_out.tx_id and tx_in.tx_out_index = tx_out.index
where stake_address.view = '<your-stake-address-here>'
  and tx_in.id is null
```

Note that these balances will not include your staking reward balance.

Comment: This is a concise and correct answer.
I ran the queries and they work just as expected.
Much appreciated, thank you!